# Why the broswer can't find the function that I have writen in java when I run the JSP web page?

Tags: java, xml, jsp, servlets, struts2

**Code:**

**printUserTable.jsp**

```jsp
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<%@ page pageEncoding="UTF-8" %>
<html>
<head>
    <title>USETABLE</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/searchPage.css">
</head>
<body>
    <form action="PrintUserTable.action" namespace="/" method="post">
        <input type="submit" value="打印表格"/>
    </form>
    <table class="hovertable">
        <tr><th colspan="5">UserTable in biosql</th></tr>
        <tr>
            <th>id</th>
            <th>username</th>
            <th>password</th>
            <th>tel</th>
            <th>mail</th>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <%
        List list = null;
        //判断session里list是否为空
        if(session.getAttribute("USERTABLEINFO") != null){
            list = (List)session.getAttribute("USERTABLEINFO");
            out.print(list);
            //判断list中的数据size是否大于0
            if(list.size()>0){
                //遍历List中的数据
                UserTable userTable;
                int idNum = 0;
                for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
                    userTable = new UserTable();
                    userTable = (UserTable) list.get(i);
                    %>
                    <tr onmouseover="this.style.backgroundColor = '#ffff66';"
                        onmouseout="this.style.backgroundColor = '#d4e3e5';">
                        <td><%=userTable.getId()%></td>
                        <td><%=userTable.getUsername()%></td>
                        <td><%=userTable.getPassword()%></td>
                        <td><%=userTable.getTel()%></td>
                        <td><%=userTable.getMail()%></td>
                    </tr>
                    <%
                }
            }
        }
    %>

</body>
</html>
```

**servlet：**

```java
package com.eodream.service;

import com.eodream.model.UserTable;
import com.eodream.util.ConnectionFactory;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * Created by Andyliwr on 2016/4/16.
 */
public class UserTableService {
    //和数据库建立连接
    private Connection dbConnection;
    //建立数据库操作执行语句变量
    private Statement st;
    //记录执行的结果
    private ResultSet rs;
    private String sql;
    private List list;
    //创建一个usertable对象
    private UserTable userTable;

    public List getUserTableInfo(){
        list = new ArrayList<>();
        //获取数据库连接
        dbConnection = ConnectionFactory.getInstance().makeConnection();
        try {
            //合成SQL语句
            st = (Statement) dbConnection.createStatement();
            sql = "SELECT * FROM biosql.usertable";
            //执行sql语句
            rs = st.executeQuery(sql);
            //获取结果集里的数据
            while(rs.next()){
                userTable = new UserTable();
                userTable.setId(rs.getInt("id"));
                userTable.setUsername(rs.getString("username"));
                userTable.setPassword(rs.getString("password"));
                userTable.setTel(rs.getString("tel"));
                userTable.setMail(rs.getString("mail"));

                //把userTable加入到list中
                list.add(userTable);
                System.out.println("List的数据有"+list.size()+"条");
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.print("合成并执行SQL语句失败");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return list;
    }

    /*//测试函数
    public static void main(String args[]){
        UserTableService userTableService = new UserTableService();
        System.out.println("查询得到的结果为："+userTableService.getUserTableInfo());
    }*/

}
```

**struts.xml and web.xml:**
**web.xml**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
         version="3.1">
    <filter>
        <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
    <!--在web.xml文件中的<welcome-file>信息中是否配置了自己工程的启动页面-->
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>PrintUserTable</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.eodream.servlet.PrintUserTable</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>PrintUserTable</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/PrintUserTable</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

**struts.xml:**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC
        "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.3//EN"
        "http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.3.dtd">

<struts>
    <package name="default" namespace="/" extends="struts-default">
        <default-action-ref name="PrintUserTable"/>
        <action name="PrintUserTable" class="com.eodream.servlet.PrintUserTable">
            <result name="success">printUserTable.jsp</result>
        </action>
    </package>
</struts>
```

Who can tell me where is the error?I have been confused in it for long. Excuse me, my English is poor...

Comment: You didn't post your browser's error.

Comment: Also you should put your java code in jsp before the closing `</table>` tag.

Comment: Any good reason to use servlets in S2? Use S2 actions.

Answer (score 0):

The action class `com.eodream.servlet.PrintUserTable` has not a method `execute()`. Since you didn't map a method for the action, the default method is `execute()`.

Either you use `method` attribute in the action config to map the action to specific method that exists in the action class or create a method `execute()`.

You can use action class that implements `Action` or extend `ActionSupport` where this interface is already implemented by default.

```
public class PrintUserTable extends ActionSupport {
...
}
```